# Как нарисовать DrawRectangle вне окна WindowForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал на *C# .NET WindowForms* свою первую простую программу, в которой рисую прямоугольники *DrawRectangle* по определенным координатам -> в окне программы в форме *pictureBox*.

При нажатии на определенную кнопку мне нужно вывести полученное изображение на экран ВНЕ окна самой программы (чтобы оно перекрывало остальные окна). **Как это сделать?**

Comment: Создайте новую форму нужного размера (или распахните её полностью) поверх других окон и в ней рисуйте.

Comment: Для меня важно, чтобы фон рисунка был полностью прозрачным

Comment: Ну задайте `TransparencyKey`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример. По нажатию на кнопку создаётся новая форма без бордюров и распахивается на весь экран. Свойством `TopMost` помещаем её поверх всех. В обработчике её события `Paint` рисуем.

Свойство `TransparencyKey` определяем цвет, который будет прозрачным. Я задал `BackColor` - цвет фона по умолчанию - так фон получается прозрачным. Нюанс в том, что при попытке рисовать именно этим цветом, ничего не будет видно. То есть, значение цвета нужно выбирать с умом.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button button;
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();            
            button = new Button { Parent = this };
            button.Click += Button_Click;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = new Form();
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            form.TopMost = true;
            form.TransparencyKey = form.BackColor;
            form.Show();
            form.Paint += Form_Paint;
        }

        private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, 200, 200, 300, 200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Есть один способ, позволяющий рисовать именно поверх других окон, а не в своём собственном. Это методы `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame` и `ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle`. Но, во-первых, цвета получаются реверсивные, во-вторых, рисунок стирается при обновлении чужих окон. Поэтому кроме как для баловства это вряд ли пригодно.